# Why ./home/Desktop is incorrect and ./Desktop is correct?

Tags: bash, shell, directory, filenames, slash

I'm learning about Linux, started yesterday. I have a question which I couldn't answer from my book or Google. What is the difference between  `./` and `/` in the shell?

I'm asking this because when I run, for example, the command `./home/yogesh/Desktop/Books`, I get this error:

```
bash: ./home/yogesh/Desktop : No such file or directory
```

However, on removing the dot it gives

```
/home/yogesh/Desktop/Books : Is a directory
```

Or, if I run `/Desktop`, it returns

```
/Desktop : No such file or directory
```

But on adding a dot before `/`, I get

```
./Desktop: is a directory
```

What is the difference between `./` and `/`?

Answer (score 1):

On unix (like on Windows), `/foo` is the location of a file or directory (absolute location, from the root directory: `/`). Whereas `./foo` is a relative location (relative to the current directory)... You can omit the leading dot + slash and just write `foo`.

By typing the command `/Desktop` or `./Desktop`, you tell the shell to execute Desktop... Which can't be executed.

`/Desktop` doesn't exist, thus the error message.

Whereas `./Desktop`, which is the absolute location `/Home/YOURNAME/Desktop` does existe. But's it's a directory, not an executable file... You probably forgot to prefix with the command to run  (typically `cd` or `ls`)

Comment: what is the difference b/w absolute location and relative location ?

Comment: Absolute position is relative to root. Relative is relative to the current directory

Answer (score 1):

Sample explanation:

`/` (slash) means root, from the root of the filesystem. So, `/home/yogesh/Desktop/Books` starts from the root, then checks for `home`, under `home` check for `yogesh` and so on. This is called an absolute path.

`.` (dot) means starting from current directory. So, if your current directory is `/home/yogesh` and you check for `./Desktop`, it is there. This is called a relative path.

Comment: More precisely, any path that does not start with a `/` is relative to the current directory.  Every directory has a file named `.` that refers to itself, hence, `./Desktop` means the the Desktop subdirectory in the current directory.  Of course, you can just drop the `./` part and it means the same thing with less typing.

Comment: @psusi, not always ./Desktop will be the same as Desktop. This is true for directories, but not for executable files. If you have executable file in current directory, do not have this directory in PATH and do not have . in PATH ./program or /path/to/program are the ways to execute it :)

Answer (score 1):

On Unix and Unix-like systems, `.` means the current directory. For example, `ls .` is the same as `ls`, it will list the contents of the current directory. So, when you use `./Desktop` as a command it finds a directory called `Desktop` that is under your current directory. You then get an error telling you that this is a directory and, therefore, cannot be executed as it is not a command.

`/` is the root of the file system. It is similar to `C:\` on Windows. When you run `/Desktop`, the system will look for a directory called `Desktop` that is in the `/` directory. That doesn't exist and it tells you so.

For example, if I am in `/home/yogesh` and I want to go to `/home/yogesh/Desktop`, I can either use the relative path (with respect to the directory I am in now) and run `cd ./Desktop` or `cd Desktop`, or I can use the absolute path and run `cd /home/yogesh/Desktop`.

Answer (score 0):

The first shouldn't be an relative location.

An relative location is to notate things shorter from within the location in which you're. 
An absolute location is from the root / which is the first directory location in Linux. When you aren't in /var you can use

```
cd /var/www
```

as /var/www an absolute location is. If you're in /var you can use

```
cd ./www
```

or

```
cd www
```

To notate it even shorter.

I recommend an free eBook of William Shotts.

Here is the link to that eBook:

[The Linux Command Line by William Shotts](http://linuxcommand.org/tlcl.php)